# Derived class Private method is getting called

Tags: c++, ooad

I have a Base class pointer pointing to derived class object. The method foo() is public in base class but private in derived class. Base class foo() is virtual. So when i call foo() from Base class pointer, Vptr Table has the address of derived class foo(), BUT its private in Derived class ...so how is it getting called.??

I understand Run time polymorphism and i also understand that the Access specifiers work for compile time and Virtual concept works at run time. So there shall be No Compiler error.

My question is : Is this is a loop hole through which we can call private methods of Derived class ? or Its expected to behave this way.
Any good Explanation for this behavior.

Thanks a lot in advance.

CODE :

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "In A";
    }
};


class B:public A
{
private:
    void foo()
    {
       std::cout << "In B ??? Its Private Method :-( ";
    }
};

int main()
{
    A* ptr = new B();
    ptr->foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's private method, but since it's virtual - it can be called.

n3690 11.5/1

> The access rules (Clause 11) for a virtual function are determined **by its declaration and are not affected by
> the rules for a function that later overrides it.**

Why this? Since

n3690 11.5/2

> Access is checked at the call point using the type of the expression used to denote the object for which the
> member function is called (B* in the example above). **The access of the member function in the class in
> which it was defined (D in the example above) is in general not known.**

Answer (score 3):

Access level is a compile-time concept. The runtime doesn't know if a method was declared `private` or `public`. Those are there for your convenience.

This is actually a good coding standard - a `virtual` method should be ideally `public` in the base class and `private` or `protected` in derived classes. This will force the caller to use the interfaces rather than the actual types (of course, this isn't always practical, but a good thing to take into account).

The concrete type is abstracted away in your case, as it should be. The base method is declared `public` and you're calling it through a pointer to a base, so it's allowed.

Comment: "[private is] a good coding standard [but] isn't always practical" it's often undesirable when it is practical - in many situations having the optimiser know the actual static type can allow inlining of virtual functions, elimination of dead code branches etc..